# Descriptive diagram with direction

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, smartdiagram

I'm new to Tikz and am working on converting SmartArt from MS PowerPoint to LaTeX.  One of my diagrams looks like this:

[image: Descriptive Diagram]

I'm aware of the package smartdiagram, and I found the "descriptive diagram", which seems somewhat close to the above.  But I am trying to show the steps of a process AND describe each of those steps (hence the directed hexagons down the left).  Is there a way to do this that already exists in smartdiagram?  Or do I need to draw my own tikzpicture?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Or, without the `smartdiagram` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,positioning}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{79,129,189}

\tikzset{
myshape/.style={
  shape=signal,
  fill=myblue,
  minimum height=1.5cm,
  minimum width=1.5cm,
  text=white,
  signal pointer angle=130,
  signal to=east,
  signal from=west,
  rotate=-90,
  transform shape
  },
mytext/.style={
  draw=myblue,
  text width=7cm,
  minimum height=1.15cm,
  thick,
  outer sep=0pt
  }  
}
\newcounter{tmp}
\newcommand\MyDesc[3][]{
\stepcounter{tmp}%
\node[myshape,#1] (desc\thetmp) {};
\node[font=\color{white}] at (desc\thetmp) {#2};
\node[mytext,anchor=north west] at (desc\thetmp.north west) 
  {%
    \parbox[t]{2em}{\hfill$\bullet$\hfill\null}%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2em\relax}{#3}%
  };
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\MyDesc{Foo 1}{Description 1}
\MyDesc[below = 1.5cm of desc1.north]{Foo 2}{Description 2}
\MyDesc[below = 1.5cm of desc2.north]{Foo 3}{Description 3}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great.  Suppose I want to get rid of the bullet.  Do I just delete `\parbox[t]{2em}{\hfill$\bullet$\hfill\null}%`?

Comment: @user1577636 Yes. Additionally, you change `\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2em\relax}{#3}` to `\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{#3}`.

Comment: @user1577636 I simplified the code in my updated answer.

Answer (score 19):

With a small patch, it is possible to achieve:

[image]

which is far from being perfect, but looks like the reference picture.

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\tikzset{description title/.append style={
    signal, 
    signal to=south, 
    signal from=north,
    yshift=-0.65cm,
  }
}
\begin{document} 
\begin{center}
\smartdiagramset{description title width=2cm, 
description title text width=1.75cm,
descriptive items y sep=2,
description text width=5.75cm,
module minimum height=1.25cm}
\smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{%
{Set up,The set up operation consist of..},
{Run, {After having set up the program, you must run..}},
{Analyse, You must check what did with analytical tools like..},}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm planning to add this feature in the new release, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yep.  In the temporary workaround above, is there a way to scale down the whole thing (i.e. an equivalent to `scale = 0.5` in tikz)?

Comment: @user1577636: sure, you can exploit `\scale` from `graphicx` package; then `\scale{0.5}{\smartdiagram[..]{..}}`.